# Join two queries with COUNT from the same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, count, outer-join

I have two queries that I run in the same table:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(up) 
FROM comentarios 
WHERE up = 1
GROUP BY id
```

And

```
SELECT id, COUNT(down) 
FROM comentarios 
WHERE down = 2
GROUP BY id
```

I tried something like this but doesn't work

```
SELECT t1.id, COUNT(t1.up), t2.id, COUNT(t2.down)
FROM (SELECT id, up FROM comentarios WHERE up = 1 GROUP BY id) t1
JOIN (SELECT id, down FROM comentarios WHERE down = 2 GROUP BY id) t2

ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Maybe a need a FULL OUTER JOIN?

What's the best way to do this in MySQL?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Have you tried a union query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN up = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UpCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN down = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DownCount
    FROM comentarios
    GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, 
    sum(case when up = 1 then 1 end) as UpCount,
    sum(case when down = 2 then 1 end) as DownCount
from comentarios  
group by id
```

Comment: wow that was fast, and new for me. The result is correct, thanks.